# What influences car braking performance besides tyres and weight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, friction, everyday-life, material-science

From time to time I stumble upon car brake tests where they test car braking performance. Usually, those vehicles are from the same weight/size class so mass stays more or less the same. Also, as much as possible, they use similarly performing tyres.
Nevertheless, the stopping distance varies, sometimes to a big degree. Considering that virtually all modern cars' braking system can apply more than enough force, causing the ABS to intervene, why does the braking distance vary so much?

Comment: Can you clear up the apparent contradiction between "so it [braking performance?] stays more or less the same" and "the stopping distance varies, sometimes to a big degree"?

Comment: The suspension system and how the weight on the tires shifts from the rear tires to the front tires under hard braking is also probably a factor in determining braking performance. Nowadays the specific type of ABS system that a car uses is also a factor.

Comment: My assumption is that if the ABS is triggered when braking, the force applied by the braking system can be taken out of the equation, the difference being made now by other things like tyres, road quality, etc. Am I right?